# StdOut is return few character

Tags: powershell-3.0

I used WinRM command to connect Linux computer and run some command. 
`StdOut` didn't return all of the result and return few character.
How can I do?

```psh
$TargetNode = '192.168.7.54'
$Password   = 'admin1'
$securePass = ConvertTo-SecureString -string $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "root", 
$SecurePass
$opt = New-CimSessionOption -UseSsl:$true -SkipCACheck:$true -SkipCNCheck:$true -SkipRevocationCheck:$true
$Sess = New-CimSession -Credential:$cred -ComputerName:$targetnode -Port:1270 -Authentication:basic -SessionOption:$opt -OperationTimeoutSec:90

$sw = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
Invoke-CimMethod -CimSession:$Sess -Namespace:"root/scx" -ClassName:"SCX_OperatingSystem" -MethodName:"ExecuteCommand" -Arguments @{   
  Command = "ls -la"; Timeout = [uint32]30
}
$sw.Stop()
$sw.Elapsed
```

Comment: What is the expected and what the actual output?

Comment: total 20&#10;drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 30 15:14 .&#10;drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Mar &#32;2 15:57 ..&#10;srwxrwxrwx 1 root root &#32; &#32;0
                  Jun 30 15:14 cim.socket&#10;-rw------- 1 root root &#32; &#32;0 Jun 30 15:14 cimserver_start.lock&#10;drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 30 19:44 loc
                 alauth&#10;-rw------- 1 root root &#32; &#32;5 Jun 30 15:14 scx-cimd.pid&#10;-rw------- 1 root root &#32; 30 Jun 24 10:34 test.log&#10;

Comment: Please edit your question. This information becomes unreadable in a comment.